# Listing files in a directory without extention in php

Tags: php

the code below should list all my files in a directory called mysubdirectory. The list must have no extention (.pdf) and the link to download each single file.
Unfortunately there are some mistakes wich i can't find becouse the files are not listed one below the other, but in horizontal and only the last one without extention.
Any suggestion? Thnks

```
 <?php 
 $string="";
 $fileCount=0;
 $filePath=$PATH.'./mysubdirectory/'; # Specify the path you want to look in. 
 $dir = opendir($filePath); # Open the path
 while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
   if (eregi("\.pdf",$file)) { # Look at only files with a .pdf extension
     $string .= "$file
 ";
     $fileCount++;
   }
 }
 if ($fileCount > 0) {
 echo sprintf("<strong>List of Files in %s</strong>%s<strong>Total Files: %s</strong>",$filePath,$string,$fileCount);
 }

 // pick up the file names, excluding extentions


 $info = pathinfo($string);
 $number =  basename($string,'.'.$info['extension']);
 echo "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/mysubdirectory/$number.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">$number</a>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `glob()` or `directoryIterator` class? Also you are concatenating your file names together without any sort of line break. Multiple whitespace charactres and/or line returns are just collapsed into a single space when HTML is output, thus they are just in a single horizontal row.

Comment: Unfortunatey no, i'm a newbie :)

Comment: @matthew Well take a look. No reason to use regex to do this.  By the way, when you do have to use regex, don't use `eregi_*` functions as they are deprecated, use `preg_*` functions. Probably glob is easier to use as someone just starting out, but I would highly recommend familiarizing yourself with directoryIterator and recursiveDirectoryIterator.  These are very powerful classes for working with the file system structure.

Comment: So how should be a working code?

Comment: I don't know :) Why don't you try to implement something and update your question if you run into any problems.